# Getting ERROR 1070 while using Enumerate on a bag in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to Enumerate a bag using the below code:

```
  DEFINE Enumerate datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate('1');

  group = GROUP data1
            By (query_text);

  ranked = FOREACH group {
        ordered = ORDER data1 BY score DESC;
        ordered = Enumerate(ordered);
        generate ordered_suggestions;
    };
```

Getting the below error:

```
220255 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
17/08/01 17:54:30 ERROR grunt.Grunt: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /mnt/var/log/pig/pig_1501609850542.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't register the jar.

```
REGISTER 's3:/<<s3-bucket-name>>/lib/datafu-1.2.0.jar';
```

This works fine:

```
 REGISTER 's3:/<<s3-bucket-name>>/lib/datafu-1.2.0.jar
 DEFINE Enumerate datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate('1');

  group = GROUP data1
            By (query_text);

  ranked = FOREACH group {
        ordered = ORDER data1 BY score DESC;
        ordered = Enumerate(ordered);
        generate ordered_suggestions;
    };
```